# Angularjs changing what makes a form $valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input box that is required, but only shows if it is needed.

```
<form name="frm" ng-submit="!frm.$valid || function()" novalidate>
    <input ng-show="something == true" type="text" ng-model="optional" required />
</form>
```

Obviously, if the input is hidden, the form will always be `$invalid`.

Is there a way to only take fields that are visible into considering if the form is valid or not?

Comment: use `ng-required="something == true"`

Comment: Have you considered using ng-if statements to load only the inputs required when a page renders?

Comment: use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`, `ng-if` create and destroy the element based on condition and it won't be taken into form fields when the condition is false

Comment: Thanks @HadiAmiri and Mike I was not aware of the differences. It worked :)